# “Je vais pas” vs “je ne vais pas”

Tags: grammaire, négation

Stromae's formidable lyrics are

> Je vais pas vous draguer, promis, juré…

I'm a beginner at French, and recently learned that is expected the form

> subject + ne + verb + pas

when you want to negate something. But there's no *ne* in his phrase, even though he means that he does not want to hit on her.

Is it a common thing not to use *ne*? Does *pas* by itself make clear that I'm negating something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "subject + ne + verb + pas" is the correct way to say it, but the "subject + verb + pas" is the informal way to say it.

Example :

> I am not a boy

Will be translated in a formal way by

> Je ne suis pas un garçon

And in an informal way

> Je suis pas un garçon

French people tend to choose the informal one in everyday life, but if you study French, I'll advise you to use the formal version.

In addition, in those lyrics of Stromae, he's playing a drunk person (falling, barely stay on his foot etc..) which justifies the use of the second version.

Comment: I'd rather say standard spoken French is dropping the *ne* while informal spoken French is merging *je* and *suis* in a single syllable, either *j'suis* or *chuis*. I believe a large majority of native French people would say *chuis pas un garçon* in real life conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a very good question. Most native speakers don't use `ne` when they speak but use it when they write. I do that too.

However, as stated above, if you study french, the best way is to use `ne` when you write so you can get a good habit in writing French. After being used to that for a while, you may remove the `ne` when you speak, as it's more French and you'll sound more like a native.

Answer (score 1):

It is really common to remove `ne` in spoken language, particularly in informal talks, with your friends or family for example, even though it is not grammatically correct.

For written language you can also skip it in informal talks, but again, it's not grammatically correct.
In formal written language you should always use `ne`